# Laravel 4 Helper class not auto-loaded

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to use a helper class in Laravel 4 in a folder located in `app/helpers`, but no matter what I do Laravel gives me error `Class was not found`

**Helper base class**

```
Helper.php
<?php
/* 
    Base Helper class!
*/

class Helpers {

}
```

**Class I'm trying to use**

```
<? 
class Gravatar extends Helpers {
 /**
     * Get either a Gravatar URL or complete image tag for a specified email address.
     *
     * @param string $email The email address
     * @param string $s Size in pixels, defaults to 80px [ 1 - 2048 ]
     * @param string $d Default imageset to use [ 404 | mm | identicon | monsterid | wavatar ]
     * @param string $r Maximum rating (inclusive) [ g | pg | r | x ]
     * @param boole $img True to return a complete IMG tag False for just the URL
     * @param array $atts Optional, additional key/value attributes to include in the IMG tag
     * @return String containing either just a URL or a complete image tag
     * @source http://gravatar.com/site/implement/images/php/
     */
    public static function get_gravatar( $email, $s = 80, $d = 'mm', $r = 'g', $img = false, $atts = array() ) {
        $url = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/';
        $url .= md5( strtolower( trim( $email ) ) );
        $url .= "?s=$s&d=$d&r=$r";
        if ( $img ) {
            $url = '<img src="' . $url . '"';
            foreach ( $atts as $key => $val )
                $url .= ' ' . $key . '="' . $val . '"';
            $url .= ' />';
        }
        return $url;
    }
}
```

This is how I try to access a function in the class in a blade file:

```
<img src="{{ Gravatar::get_gravatar($thread['user']['email'], 50) }}">
```

I have included the folder in global.php and composer.json. I have also tried running `composer dump-autoload` with no avail.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

In the Gravatar.php the `<?` should be `<?php` and now it works!